# Magento 2: Adding a Javascript library

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I am trying to add an animation library called [Sal](https://github.com/mciastek/sal), built on pure Javascript (Does not rely on jQuery). Maybe I am missing something, but I followed the instructions on adding via require-config, and I am getting a `sal is not defined` error.

I have also tried just adding the js file via `default_head_blocks.xml`

My `require-config.js`

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'sal': 'js/sal'
    },
    deps: [
        "js/script",
        "js/main"
    ]
};
```

My `main.js`

```
define(['sal'], function(){
  "use strict";
  sal();
  console.log(" ====== main.js is loaded====== ");
});
```

Comment: Please provide info with full module paths. Perhaps you have your js libs in wrong directories ;)

Comment: @dudzio perhaps! Here they are:  
`VENDOR/themename/require-config.js`  

`VENDOR/themename/web/js/sal.js`  

`VENDOR/themename/web/js/script.js` (Contains other JS unrelated to Sal)  

`VENDOR/themename/web/js/main.js` (Contains my JS and trying to initialize Sal inside)  

For context, I also importing a slider named Flickity, and it works fine (I didn't include it in my initial example)